# Vue: is it possible to bind an event to a component when input emits a false value?

Tags: vue.js

I want a clean way to bind a function to when vuetify's v-dialog closes.

the v-dialog component does not have an on close event - it has the input event, emitting true for open and false for closed. I want to bind an event to the input - only when it emits false (i.e. - the dialog closed).

Right now the best way I can think of it to put a watcher on the value used in v-model and to check if the old value is true and the new value is false within the watcher handler. Is there a better way?

Is there a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<v-dialog @input="(value) => !value && yourMethod()"></v-dialog>
```

I think this is the best and clean way to do it.